# Ionic Appflow and GitHub Connection List is incomplete and entry to Repo missing

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native, ionic-appflow

I am currently trying to connect a GitHub Repo to Ionic App Flow. 
Therefore, I have set up everything as proposed.

1. Install ionic CLI as suggested by `npm install -g @ionic/cli`
2. Created local App
3. Created App in App Flow dashboard
4. Set up SSH Key to GitHub

Additionally, I am admin in the GitHub Repo, yet I am not the owner of it.

If i want to connect the App Flow App to my GitHub Repo i do the following as instructed:

1. I link the ionic app by `ionic link XXXXX`
2. Following the instructions
3. Which git host would you like to use? >> GitHub.
4. Does the repository exist on GitHub? (Y/n) >> Y.

This is when the trouble kicks in. I am asked to auth to Github and get 
back a list of all Repos I have access too. However, the one I am admin at
and want to connect the Repo to is not listed.

Same case in the dashboard under `AppName > Settings > Git`
All my personal repos and to I am Collaborater at are shown, but not the 
one I am looking for. Can someone help and tell my why this is the case
and how to resolve this issue?

Constructive help appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this myself. Go to the Github organization's settings page, and on the Third-party access tab - turn off the application access restrictions. Then on the Ionic dashboard your organization should appear in the dropdown.